# Sequelize Where Not Exists with user provided variables

Tags: sequelize.js

I have three tables; Customers, Orders and Timereports. I want to find all Orders that have a minimum of minutes to be reported in each month but where no timereports have been made in the requested month.

Associations are that Customers have many Orders and Orders have many Timereports.

I got the following SQL to work as intended, with the exception that month and year will be user provided variables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
LEFT JOIN Orders 
ON Customers.id = Orders.CustomerId 
WHERE Orders.minutesPerWeek > 0
AND Orders.status = 'Active'
AND NOT EXISTS ( 
SELECT * FROM Timereports 
WHERE Timereports.OrderId = Orders.id 
AND month(Timereports.startTime) = 8 
AND year(Timereports.startTime) = 2022)
```

My Sequelize code so far is the following:

```
var requestedDate = new Date();

  if (req.query.month) {
    requestedDate.setMonth(req.query.month - 1);
  }
  if (req.query.year) {
    requestedDate.setFullYear(req.query.year);
  }
const test = await db.Customer.findAll({
    include: {
      model: db.Order,
      where: {
        minutesPerWeek: { [Op.gt]: 0 },
        status: "Active",
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: db.Timereport,
          where: {
            startTime: sequelize.where(
              sequelize.fn("month", sequelize.col("startTime")),
              requestedDate.getMonth() + 1
            ),
            [Op.and]: [
              {
                startTime: sequelize.where(
                  sequelize.fn("year", sequelize.col("startTime")),
                  requestedDate.getFullYear()
                ),
              },
            ],
          },
          required: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    });
```

Which is missing the Not Exists part. How can i change my code to match my SQL query plus the user provided requested date?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sequelize.where` in conjunction with `Sequelize.literal` like this:

```js
 [Op.and]: [
              {
                startTime: sequelize.where(
                  sequelize.fn("year", sequelize.col("startTime")),
                  requestedDate.getFullYear()
                ),
              },
              Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal(`NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Timereports 
WHERE Timereports.OrderId = Orders.id 
AND month(Timereports.startTime) = @month
AND year(Timereports.startTime) = @year))`), '=', true)
            ],
```

Most likely you will need to change the name of `Orders.id` to a correct alias that will be generated from `Order` model in this query.

Also you need to indicate `month` and `year` parameters in `bind` option like this:

```js
await db.Customer.findAll({
 bind: {
   month: 8,
   year: 2022
 },
 include: [
 // rest of parameters
```